# sizeof() returning inconsistent result, OSX

Tags: c++, macos, sizeof

When I call `sizeof(wchar_t)` on my OSX10_8 machine in a simple "hello world" type program, I get back 4 bytes as I would expect for a machine using UTF-32. However, when I call it from a testing program I'm using validate the behaviour of an app I wrote, I get back 1 byte.

The only difference I can see between the testing program and the hello world program is that the testing program uses a `typedef`:

```
#ifdef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
typedef wchar_t SQLWCHAR;
#else
typedef unsigned short SQLWCHAR;
#endif
```

---

When I call `sizeof()` in my test program

```
 VerifyAndThrow( 
            (int) sizeof(SQLWCHAR), 
            (int) bufferLength, 
            SBT_L( "The last call to SqlGetData should return 5 characters" ), 
            SBODBC_FILELINE );
```

The first argument passed in to `VerifyAndThrow()` is 1.

Can someone explain the reason for this discrepancy? Is it something to do with the `typedef`? I don't think it's because `wchat_t` is not defined. If that were the case I would expect `sizeof()` to return the size of an `unsigned short`, which on a UTF-32 machine is two bytes.

Comment: The snippets on their own don't indicate what the issue is; however I'd put in some debug prior to the invocation of VerifyAndThrow (i.e. dump the sizeof's there as well) because it's either going to be `2` or `4` depending on the definition of `_WCHAR_T_DEFINED`, and we've no idea if that is defined; as C++ doesn't need to `#include` anything for `wchar_t`

Comment: You should be able to test this hypothesis with a much simpler bit of code: http://ideone.com/rlTPGC. An [mcve] as it's sometimes called.

Comment: So it turns out SQLWCHAR is a typedef of unsigned short. Which is two bytes. I agree with @Petesh, sizeof should either be returning 2 bytes or 4 bytes. I don't understand how it's even possible to return 1. Could the test platform be somehow overwriting the size of an unsigned short? Is that even possible?